# The problem of apt fix-broken install in Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, cuda, environment

When I need to use apt-get to install somethings.

```
$sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool curl make g++ unzip  

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
make is already the newest version (4.1-9.1ubuntu1).
unzip is already the newest version (6.0-21ubuntu1).
unzip set to manually installed.
curl is already the newest version (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8).
g++ is already the newest version (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3).
g++ set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 autoconf : Depends: m4 (>= 1.4.13)
 automake : Depends: autotools-dev (>= 20020320.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libtool : Depends: autotools-dev but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libltdl-dev but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After I got this error message, I tried to fix it.

However, when I typed 'sudo apt --fix-broken install', I got this error below.

```
$sudo apt --fix-broken install                                                                                                                                      

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
Recommended packages:
  libnvcuvid1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
38 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/263 MB of archives.
After this operation, 734 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 222357 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-cuda-dev (9.1.85-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In here, I already faced this problem many times about nvidia-cuda-dev.
I installed cuda 10.2 version. But I don't know why it wanna use version 9?
But I need this version(10.2), and I don't want to change it that I am afraid of my environment which will get wrong.

```
$nvcc --version 

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

Sorry I am not familiar with setting of environment here. 
Is there any suggestion about this situation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would start by providing your OS/release details.  Yes I could guess using (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=make) et.al., but it's better if you provide exact details. You're also wanting packages (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=nvidia-cuda-dev&searchon=names) for a different release to what you appear from prior detail to have installed; so your question is vague & contradicts itself.

Comment: I was not sure that should I provide what information which is enough useful for you.
Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` depends on `nvidia-cuda-dev`. `nvidia-cuda-dev` contains the file `/usr/include/cublas.h` which is also in package `libcublas-dev` so only one of those two packages can be installed at the same time, and currently that's `libcublas-dev`.

So basically you can have either `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` or `libcublas-dev` but not both. Remove one of them.

It seems `libcublas-dev` is made for another distro or Ubuntu version and not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! You also mentioned very important information to me. 
It worked for me.

Comment: @chiehpower If this answer worked for you, please accept it by clicking the check mark on the left. This helps future visitors know that this was the solution, thanks.

Comment: Sure! Sorry I first time used it so not familiar. I accepted it!